# iOS deep link only works once after launch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, deep-linking

I'm using this function in AppDelegate.swift to deep link to a specific ViewController:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool{
    if(url.host == "myviewcontroller"){
        window?.rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("DeepLinkToPushMessage", sender: nil)

    }
    return true
```

This is in my info.plist: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=2d634c-1464972321.jpg

Deep linking to a specific ViewController is working like this: myapp://myviewcontroller

But unfortunately it only works once. I have to restart my app to make deep linking workable again otherwise it only opens my app without deep linking to the ViewController.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that the function you are using is just only called once. Try to print something inside the function to check if it's called more then once per app run.

Comment: No, the function is always called. I took this: if(url.host == "push"){ print("It's working"). It always prints "It's working". Do you have an other idea?

Comment: Can nobody help me?

Comment: Have a solution to this issue been proposed?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with a QR Reader I was building my solution as to add a .stoprunning and a .startrunning at the bottom of the function to keep it from just stopping and crashing the app after it read a QR code once. not sure if this will solve your issue or not.

below is my code

```
extension QRViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
        func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
            // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object
            if metadataObjects.isEmpty {
                qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
                
                captureSession.stopRunning()
                captureSession.startRunning()
                return
```